# Integrate JNI into SpringBoot using cmake in Gradle similarly to Android

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to use cmake plugin to build and integrate native C library 
in a SpringBoot application. I would like to use it similarly to Android. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds. The problem with Spring Boot is that how to integrate cmake. The problem comes from the tag -android- the Gradle build does not recognise/ is undefined.

Android example:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {...}
```

This what I have tried:

```
build {
   cmake {
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
   }
}
```

> Could not find method cmake() for arguments [build_b3o7iuvk0awnx464p5v0i5gx$_run_closure3$_closure6@5f8a6ff6] on task ':build' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

Comment: java is not android, so android plugin magic wont work like that.

Comment: I know that but I would like to use cmake in a similar fashion.